# C# vs VB6: How to get IME Unicode Char assosiated with an ANSI Window (UC or PictureBox)

Tags: c#, unicode, vb6, ansi, ime

In VB6,UserControl or Form or PictureBox is ANSI window in locale English 1033 (configurable in Region and Language settings). I see wParam is always 63 (Char '?') in WM_IME_CHAR or WM_UNICHAR or WM_CHAR when I am typing Unicode via MS IME or Baidu input.

For Comparison, I creates a SDK TextBox, used by CreateWindowExW API, IsWindowUnicode API shows it is Unicode window, Since it is Unicode Window, I can see wParam is Unicode Keycode When I subclass WM_IME_CHAR and WM_UNICHAR and WM_CHAR. So I can get Unicode Char easily.

I guess OS deal with ANSI window and Unicode Window is different. What is the work-around to get IME Unicode Char?

The same code in C# works with whatever locale either 1033 (English USA) or 2052 (Chinese PRC), since C# window is always Unicode.

```html
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
    int msg = m.Msg;
    if (msg == WM_IME_SETCONTEXT) //associated IME with our UserControl
       {
         if (!m.WParam.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
          {
           bool flag = ImmAssociateContextEx(m.HWnd, IntPtr.Zero, 16);
           IntPtr hIMC = ImmGetContext(m.HWnd);
           flag = ImmSetOpenStatus(hIMC, true);
           flag = ImmReleaseContext(m.HWnd, hIMC);
          }
        }
    }
    else
    if (msg == WM_IME_CHAR) //Intercept Message to get Unicode Char
      {
        KeyPress(this, new KeyPressEventArgs(Strings.ChrW(m.WParam.ToInt32())));
        return;
      }
    }
   base.WndProc(ref m);
}

In VB6 UserControl:
Private Function WindowProcUserControl(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
   Select Case wMsg
    Case WM_IME_SETCONTEXT '//associated IME with our UserControl
         If Not wParam = 0 Then
            Dim flag As Boolean
            flag = ImmAssociateContextEx(hWnd, 0, 16)
            If flag Then
               Dim hIMC As Long
               hIMC = ImmGetContext(hWnd)
               flag = ImmSetOpenStatus(hIMC, True)
               flag = ImmReleaseContext(hWnd, hIMC)
            End If
         End If
     Case WM_IME_CHAR '//Intercept Message to get Unicode Char
         Call KeyPress(ChW$(wParam And &HFFFF&))
         Exit Function 
  End Select
End Function
```

Comment: It is hard but still doable. -- see [page 14 of this long thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)/page14) on vbforums. Search for unicode message pump (which turns out is not needed).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But Krool's TextBox is Unicode Window so that the wParam is Unicode KeyCode. For UC or Form or PictureBox, it is ANSI window in locale=1033 (English,USA), In Subclass procedure,wParam is always 63 when I typing Unicode. This is root problem. The only way may subclass IMM window,I guess.
Easily tested by:                                                                                            
Private Declare Function IsWindowUnicode Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Comment: You can "turn" any hWnd to unicode with Get/SetWindowLong**W** on `GWL_WNDPROC` so `IsWindowUnicode` tests positive if you think that this might be your problem. VB's ANSI message pump is still a bigger problem IMHO. Krool hacked unicode support w/o resorting to get message hooks (as I did in a project of mine) which is good. You have to figure it out why his code works ok and you have problems in your case.

Comment: If you are convenient, please post your tricks on VBForums since TextBox is very basic and foundational control everyone use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root problem is that VB6 windows are ANSI, When an IME window attach to them, VB6 just handle by ANSI APIs (may say "VB's ANSI pump will eat it"). Since this problem is beyond mine and most of programmers capability, I let this thread 'solved' falsely.